# Radio start / stop and start again

Tags: android, deezer

I'm having a problem with the Android SDK (deezer-sdk-0.10.16) and playing Radio.

When I send the 'mPlayer.skipToNextTrack();' sometimes (but a lot of times), the player change the music, the album cover and start to play the next music for 1~2 sec, and next stop the music for about 1~2 sec and then start it all over again. But sometimes it's fine and work very well!

I have some logs from the events. The test was in WiFi network, but the same behavior happens in the 3G network, and with almost the same rate.

When it's fine and not stopped the music:

```
    12-03 10:47:26.082: D/Radio(23596): onPlayerStateChange: PlayerState: STOPPED / arg1: 6813
    12-03 10:47:26.102: D/Radio(23596): onPlayerStateChange: PlayerState: INITIALIZING / arg1: 0
    12-03 10:47:26.112: D/Radio(23596): onPlayerStateChange: PlayerState: READY / arg1: 0
    12-03 10:47:26.132: D/Radio(23596): onPlayTrack: Title: País do Futebol (feat. Emicida)
    12-03 10:47:26.132: D/Radio(23596): onPlayerStateChange: PlayerState: WAITING_FOR_DATA / arg1: 0
    12-03 10:47:27.043: D/Radio(23596): onPlayerStateChange: PlayerState: PLAYING / arg1: 0
```

And this log it's when we have the problem:

```
    12-03 10:48:32.397: D/Radio(23596): onPlayerStateChange: PlayerState: STOPPED / arg1: 5812
    12-03 10:48:32.627: D/Radio(23596): onPlayerStateChange: PlayerState: INITIALIZING / arg1: 0
    12-03 10:48:32.637: D/Radio(23596): onPlayerStateChange: PlayerState: READY / arg1: 0
    12-03 10:48:32.647: D/Radio(23596): onPlayTrack: Title: Fugidinha
    12-03 10:48:32.677: D/Radio(23596): onPlayerStateChange: PlayerState: WAITING_FOR_DATA / arg1: 0
    12-03 10:48:33.838: D/Radio(23596): onPlayerStateChange: PlayerState: PLAYING / arg1: 0
    12-03 10:48:36.080: D/Radio(23596): onTrackEnded: Title: Fugidinha
    12-03 10:48:36.080: D/Radio(23596): onPlayerStateChange: PlayerState: PLAYBACK_COMPLETED / arg1: 191067
    12-03 10:48:38.623: D/Radio(23596): onPlayerStateChange: PlayerState: STOPPED / arg1: 191067
    12-03 10:48:38.623: D/Radio(23596): onPlayerStateChange: PlayerState: INITIALIZING / arg1: 0
    12-03 10:48:38.643: D/Radio(23596): onPlayerStateChange: PlayerState: READY / arg1: 0
    12-03 10:48:38.643: D/Radio(23596): onPlayTrack: Title: Fugidinha
    12-03 10:48:38.653: D/Radio(23596): onPlayerStateChange: PlayerState: WAITING_FOR_DATA / arg1: 0
    12-03 10:48:40.355: D/Radio(23596): onPlayerStateChange: PlayerState: PLAYING / arg1: 0
```

I'm looking to solve this case, or at least intercept the 'stop' command from the sdk and not really 'stop' the music.

Kind regards,
William Bertan